# Laravel 4.2 : Cron command not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron, command, command-line-interface

I wish to execute a artisan command from a cron

```
php -c path/php.ini path_folder_project/artisan robot:hydrate-live
```

Here I use a php.ini personified to avoid this error :

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: argv'
```

But my cron always  gives me this error :

```
 exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'There are no commands defined in the "robot" namespace.'
```

I tried to execute a simple `php artisan list` since my cron.. And actually my order does not exist when I pass by the cron

Comment: You should explain what's the problem. What does it mean `I tried to execute a simple php artisan list since my cron` ? Do you have registered `robot:hydrate-live`command at all?

Comment: I wanted to say, when I execute this cron
`* * * * * php -c path/php.ini path_folder_project/artisan list`
my command does not exist in the list

Comment: What happens if you run it without cron? Do you get artisan commands list?

Comment: I have all commands
`Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]
...
robot
  robot:hydrate-live          ?`